# Embedding controls within ListView in XAML

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, xslt

I need to create a list of items in a WPF project for displaying a correspondence between an XML file and the appropiate XSLT file that must process it. Conceptually, it would be something like this:

```
[xml file name][button]   [combobox]
```

that is, a grid with two columns, first column should show a text box and a button.

The text box would show the xml filename and the button would allow the user to select the file.

Second column would be just a combo box containing a list of pre-existing xslt files.

I would appreciate some introductory sample to create something like this as I don't have much WPF expertise.

I have read topics on DataTemplates, View models and the like but didn't find anything similar for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF `DataTemplate`to achieve this. I dont know whether you are using MVVM or not and how your code-behind is structured but the XAML should be roughly like :

```
<ListView ItemsSource=<your_list_of_XML_files> ... >
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" >
           <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
           <Button/>
         </StackPanel>
         <ComboBox ItemsSource=<your_list_of_XSLT_files> Grid.Column="1" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```